# Why cannot the comments be used within the tokens?

Tags: c, compiler-construction

If I have a code ,like

```
 int main()
    {
        i/* this is me*/nt a=9;
        printf("%d",a);
        getch();
        return 0;
    }
```

Here If I try to use comment within the token int then what problem it creates for because of which it shows error.what problem arises in the compiler when in the lexical phases the lexical analyzer just converts the stream of characters into tokens ,and it removes all the comments ,so then what is the problem here ?

Comment: I don't think that it would be fundamentally impossible to define the language such that your construct were possible.  However, I'm very happy it wasn't designed that way.  It would lead to very confusing bugs and I have never missed that “feature” so far.  Why would you like to have a comment inside an identifier anyway?

Answer (score 9):

See [5.1.1.2/3 in the C11 Standard](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#5.1.1.2)

> Each comment is replaced by one space character.

Comment: The alternative, replacing a comment with nothing, may lead to quite unpredictable bugs -- probably more than treating a comment as a whitespace separator.

Answer (score 3):

Because the C language is specified to forbid that. Intuitively, comments are space-like. You can imagine that the compiler parses every comments as a space.

You might be interested in the [preprocessor replacement](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/preprocessor/replace) abilities. Read about its [concatenation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Concatenation.html) & [stringification](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Stringification.html) abilities (inside macros).

There is also a pragmatical reason to forbid comments *inside* lexical tokens: it would make the source code *very unreadable* by humans.

Also, permitting comments inside tokens would likely make the parser slower.

<sup>I know no programming language accepting comments inside tokens.</sup>

In the 1970s & 1980s, most C compilers effectively run a separate preprocessor process (`/lib/cpp`) which generated a preprocessed file which was parsed by the real compiler (`cc1`, which produced an assembler file). Today, the preprocessor is actually part of the `cc1` compiler (in [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) it is the `libcpp/` internal library) -somehow working as a lexer since producing a virtual stream of tokens- and no preprocessed file is generally written to the disk.

Comment: So basically is the temp file made by the lexical analyzer contains white space characters and then it is passed to the parser,Am I correct?

Comment: Not really today, but your picture was right in the previous century.

Comment: Is it true that all whitespace characters in the source code like tabs ,newline characters all are replaced by a single white space ,so is there any representation for them in the temp file formed by the lexical analyzer,so then how is the differentiation made between tabs and newline characters while parsing ,say for example ,in printf statements we give tabs and newline characters ,so then how will the parser work ,then if whitespaces characters dealt with by the lexical analyzer ,I am totally confused how whitespaces are dealt with?

Comment: There is a pragmatic reason to allow comments inside tokens, and in fact forbidding them is what leads to very unreadable source code. Namely, long tokens. C already does some handstands to allow single-line strings to span multiple lines, indicating the language designers were aware of this issue. They just didn't do it for 1000-character identifiers, which NEED IT.